How can I ensure that the data ranges for the scatter plots are correctly set based on the user input?
I am working on a VBA project in Excel where I need to create scatter plots dynamically based on user input. The data is stored in a table, and the ranges for the scatter plots need to be determined dynamically. I have a script that generates a table based on user input. The table includes multiple series of data.
I need to create three different scatter plots from this table, with the ranges for each plot determined by the user input. There are two different routines: one for building the table and another for creating the graphs.
Here's the table:

I've tried export the endRow value from the for loop with the numSeries to a dictionary and exporting it. However, the exporting it somehow always get the wrong ranges no matter how I try. I am expecting it to be printing out 3 different graphs with X amount of series (based on user input).
Here are the relevant VBA procedures I have so far:
Routine 1: Build the Table
Dim seriesEndRows() As Long

Sub MainProcedure()
    Call AskForInput
    Call StoreEndRows
    Call MakeAllGraphs
End Sub

Sub AskForInput()
    ' User input and table generation code...
End Sub

Sub StoreEndRows()
    Dim wsControl As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, K As Integer
    Dim startRow As Long, seriesEndRow As Long
    Dim numSeries As Integer
    Dim seriesIndex As Integer
    
    Set wsControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
    
    startRow = 2
    seriesIndex = 1 ' Initialize the series index
    ReDim seriesEndRows(1 To numVariables * numSeries) ' Adjust size as needed

    For i = 1 To numVariables
        Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
        Dim txtBox As MSForms.TextBox
        On Error Resume Next
        Set chkBox = UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i)
        If chkBox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If chkBox.Value = True Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set txtBox = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & i)
            If txtBox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            On Error GoTo 0
            numSeries = Val(txtBox.Text)
        Else
            numSeries = 1
        End If
        
        For K = 1 To numSeries
            seriesEndRow = startRow
            Do Until wsControl.Cells(seriesEndRow, 1).Value = "" ' Find end of series
                seriesEndRow = seriesEndRow + 1
            Loop
            seriesEndRow = seriesEndRow - 1
            
            seriesEndRows(seriesIndex) = seriesEndRow ' Store the end row
            seriesIndex = seriesIndex + 1
            
            startRow = seriesEndRow + 1
        Next K
    Next i
End Sub


Routine 2: Creating the Graphs
Sub MakeAllGraphs()
    Dim wsControl As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim seriesEndRow As Long
    Dim seriesIndex As Integer
    
    Set wsControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
    
    ' Loop to create 3 graphs
    seriesIndex = 1
    For i = 1 To 3
        If seriesIndex <= UBound(seriesEndRows) Then
            seriesEndRow = seriesEndRows(seriesIndex)
        Else
            MsgBox "Series index " & seriesIndex & " exceeds array bounds."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Set chartObj = wsControl.ChartObjects.Add(left:=100, width:=375, top:=50 + (i - 1) * 300, height:=225)
        With chartObj.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            
            Select Case i
                Case 1 ' Buckle vs RDI
                    .SetSourceData Source:=wsControl.Range("K2:K" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = wsControl.Range("D2:D" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = wsControl.Range("K2:K" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Buckle vs RDI"
                
                Case 2 ' RDI vs Growth
                    .SetSourceData Source:=wsControl.Range("J2:J" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = wsControl.Range("D2:D" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = wsControl.Range("J2:J" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "RDI vs Growth"
                
                Case 3 ' RDI vs Flange Avg
                    .SetSourceData Source:=wsControl.Range("H2:H" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = wsControl.Range("D2:D" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = wsControl.Range("H2:H" & seriesEndRow)
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "RDI vs Flange Avg"
            End Select
            
            .HasTitle = True
            Select Case i
                Case 1
                    .ChartTitle.Text = "Buckle vs RDI"
                Case 2
                    .ChartTitle.Text = "RDI vs Growth"
                Case 3
                    .ChartTitle.Text = "RDI vs Flange Avg"
            End Select
        End With
        
        seriesIndex = seriesIndex + 1
    Next i
End Sub



Bit tricky with no data in your screenshot, but should (eg) Series 1 be from row2 to row 6 ?  And should all variables for the same Series share the same start/end rows?

@TimWilliams Correct. I have updated the image to show with some dummy data. Each of the 3 variable with the  same series should have the same start/end rows respectfully. Hope it helps.

Are you able to share a workbook with just a sample table of data?  No macros or anything else...

OK.  Why not instead store the start/end rows when you create the table?

I might approach it something like this:
Sub MakeAllGraphs()
    Dim wsControl As Worksheet
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Dim i As Integer, ttl As String, xcol, ycol
    Dim seriesEndRow As Long
    Dim seriesIndex As Integer, col As Collection, rng As Range
    
    Set wsControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
    
    Set col = GetDataRanges() 'get data blocks
    
    wsControl.DrawingObjects.Delete 'delete existing plots
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        
        'assign title, x values column, y values column
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                ttl = "Buckle vs RDI"
                xcol = "D"
                ycol = "K"
            Case 2
                ttl = "RDI vs Growth"
                xcol = "D"
                ycol = "J"
            Case 3
                ttl = "RDI vs Flange Avg"
                xcol = "D"
                ycol = "H"
        End Select
        
        Set chartObj = wsControl.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, _
                                    Top:=50 + (i - 1) * 300, Height:=225)
        With chartObj.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = ttl
            
            For Each rng In col
                With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    .XValues = rng.Columns(xcol)
                    .Values = rng.Columns(ycol)
                    .Name = rng.Cells(1).Value & ":" & rng.Cells(2).Value
                End With
            Next rng
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub



'return a collection of ranges, where each range is a block
'  of rows representing a series variable
Function GetDataRanges() As Collection
    Const START_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim col As New Collection, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long
    Dim c As Range, m
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control")
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last used row
    
    Set c = ws.Cells(START_ROW, "A") 'starting here
    Do
        'find the next "Max" in Col A
        m = Application.Match("Max", c.Offset(1).Resize(100), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            col.Add c.EntireRow.Resize(m) 'add the rows for this block to the collection
            Set c = c.Offset(m + 4)       'skip to next start row
        Else
            Exit Do 'no more data
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetDataRanges = col
End Function

